# Add empty table to table with data

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner. I make my project in PHP and Laravel 8.
I have this $array:

```
array:1 [▼
  "attributes" => array:37 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "hash" => "19f149b6-f7e2-4d61-b3c5-d46ebc92f681"
    "hidden_carrier_data" => 0
    "delivery_name_surname" => null
    "delivery_signature_binary" => null
    "disable_change_status_driver" => 0
  ]
]
```

I need add OLD to this array:

```
array:1 [▼
  "old" => array:0
  "attributes" => array:37 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "hash" => "19f149b6-f7e2-4d61-b3c5-d46ebc92f681"
    "hidden_carrier_data" => 0
    "delivery_name_surname" => null
    "delivery_signature_binary" => null
    "disable_change_status_driver" => 0
  ]
]
```

How can I make it?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out

```
$array["old"] = [...something];
```

Let me know this worked or not.